# "Homotopy theory" on finite topological spaces?

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics, homotopy-theory

My question concerns finite sets carrying a not-necessarily-discrete topology. I'm wondering if there's an analogue for homotopy theory where the role of $S^n$ is played by some other, finite set. (My preliminary thoughts involved cyclic groups with the discrete topology playing the role of $S^1$, but I can't be sure yet if this goes anywhere.)

Reading up, I found that, perhaps unsurprisingly, discrete homotopy theories for graphs have been studied, for example in G. Malle, *A Homotopy Theory for Graphs*, Glasnik Matematicki, 18 (1983), 3-25, and they exhibit precisely the behavior one expects of them. But, this is something of a proper subset of what I'm looking for, and in many ways the theories are of a "less topological" flavor than I would prefer.

This is primarily a reference request, but if anyone has ideas or examples I should be keeping in mind I would be equally appreciative for those.

Comment: In addition to McCord, you might also want to take a look at Peter May's (unpublished) [book](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/FINITEBOOK/FiniteAugBOOK.pdf) on finite spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^1$ is actually weakly homotopy equivalent to the [pseudocircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle) $P$. It is therefore possible to replace $S^1$ with a finite space in many cases, for example the fundamental group $[S^1,X]$ is naturally isomorphic to $[P,X]$ (for all, not just finite $X$). A similar construction works for the higher homotopy groups as any finite simplicial complex (like the $n$-sphere) is weakly homotopy equivalent to a finite topological space.

Comment: Oh, that's quite nice. This answer pointed me to a paper by McCord which appears to be the source of the assertion in your last sentence, which ought to keep me busy for a while. Thanks.

Comment: It is not true that $[S^1,X]\cong [P,X]$, since you have only a weak homotopy equivalence, not a homotopy equivalence.